# Load form and use custom submit handler

Tags: 8, forms

In my Controller I'm loading a form with the following code.

```
$form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\custom_module\Form\CustomForm');
```

Depending on different cases I would like to use different processing of the form.

I see 3 possibilities to handle this:

1. Use different forms and load the correct depending on the case
2. Include some hidden fields and evaluate these fields in the submit handler of the form
3. Use different submit handlers

I think the third possibility is the best one. But when I try to use a custom submit hanlders.

```
$form['#submit'] = 'custom_module_form_submit';
// or
$form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'custom_module_form_submit';
```

They both don't work. How can this be achieved? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: _Is there a better way of doing this?_ Yes, use a form builder directly.

Comment: What do you mean? How?

Comment: You should already have a form builder, if you are using `$form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\custom_module\Form\CustomForm');`. Otherwise, that could would give an error. `Drupal\custom_module\Form\C‌​ustomForm` is supposed to be a form builder class.

Comment: yes its a custom class extending FormBase. But I still don't  get how to change the submit handler. In my controller I am successfully loading and also rendering the form. Now I would like to perform different action depending on some cases and therefor use different submit handlers depending on how the form should be processed.

Comment: Does the action depend on the clicked button? For example, do you have a _Delete_, _Create new copy_, and _Save button_?

Comment: No, it depends on some parameters in the url and values from a get/post request.

Comment: Just check those values in the form submission handler. There is no need to have different submission handlers.

Comment: What you're trying to do can't be done and instead you need hook_form_alter or see 4k4 answer.

Answer (score 1):

@kiamlaluno is right, you have to use the form builder directly. But for this question in the comments there is a solution:

> ... its a custom class extending FormBase. But I still don't get how
>   to change the submit handler. In my controller ...

you can put additional parameters in `formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\custom_module\Form\CustomForm', $param)`, which you then can use in the form class to build the form differently, for example add different submit handlers:

```
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $param = NULL) {

    if ($param == 1) {
      $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'custom_module_form_submit';
    }

  }
```